# DocPad slow on livereload and docpad server reloading every time

Tags: docpad

I'm fighting for some time with docpad performance in local development. Have issue with live reload. Small change in some less file takes even 100sec to regenerate and reload the server. It looks like even though there was a change in one file, he regenerates everything. I've added those, as suggested on docpad page:

```
watchOptions: 
  preferredMethods: ['watchFile','watch']
  catchupDelay: 0 
regenerateDelay: 0
```

also disabled tag plugin for local dev, as he is pretty nasty with its constant tags regeneration.

I'm on docpad 6.63.8 with the following plugins: coffeescript, eco, gulp, highlightjs, less, livereload, lunr, marked, paged, partials, tags, text

I thought that I will simply get over it with gulp watch, but obviously watch is not enough, server needs to be reloaded anyway and I don't think it is possible to replace livereload plugin with gulp livereload or I'm just to stupid to do this

I'm using text plugin a lot, and maybe it slows down?

I wanted to overcome the issue by using gulp for watching and regeneration and manual restart of the server and `docpad server` but I noticed that docpad server is regenerating all the files, even though they were already regenerated and are in the out dir.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yep - I've seen this problem with livereload. I see it especially with dynamic pages. To be honest I think the best solution for the moment is to just remove livereload - remove it from the package.json file and delete the livereload node_modules directory. To my mind, livereload is only saving you from having to hit the reload button on the browser.

Comment: yeah, thing is that restarting the server to see a small change in less or js is a bit frustrating ... if you have a huge project that starts for few minutes

Comment: I'm confused. Livereload shouldn't influence whether you have to restart the server or not. All it should be doing is forcing your browser to reload any changes.

Comment: yeap, problem with livereload is one thing, problem with server reloading is another - but both of the bring frustration. I've already resigned from using livereload, and for the server reload and regeneration I'm using https://github.com/foreverjs/forever - and now I'm pretty much safe (tested it for few days) that every change is picked up and server restarts. The only problem that stays is that I think when reloading, docpad is rebuilding everything from scratch, and not just the changed files

Comment: My instant response is that I would expect the server to regenerate everything on load. Docpad doesn't have a database that records when a file was last generated

Comment: but he knows what files were changed, and what other files depend on it, so it suggest that it can regenerate only changed files

Comment: Sorry - docpad does maintain a database of changes, but this is an in-memory database. It's not persisted to disk - although I'm willing to be corrected on this.